# Cross-browser removal of table cell padding/spacing

Tags: css, cross-browser, cell, css-tables

How does one remove that annoying cell spacing and/or padding in a table structure, using css?  Double props if the solution works in IE7-9, Firefox, and Chrome!

[image]

### Why must CSS be so difficult!  It's maddening!

Comment: could we see the code or a demo site?

Comment: Why not just set your styles on the rows instead of each cell? That should fix the problem according to all that you have given us to see.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, this is resolved using `cellspacing: collapse;` in your css rules for that table.

Comment: Test in IE7-9, Chrome, and Firefox (6+).  Vote up for @Joseph as well for an actual example too!  You guys rock!

Answer (score 1):

`table { border-spacing: 0 }` should do the trick.